# How to create a Buy link like coinbase in Metamask

Tags: private-blockchain

When I'm using Metamask using Main Ethereum Network, and click on the [Buy] button, I will be presented with two links (Coinbase, ShapeShift).

May I know how can I create link like these? I would like to create one in my privatenode for testing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use client side JavaScript.

[Include web3.js as a dependency for your page.](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/)

Create a clickable button that calls JavaScript function.

[Initialize Web3 instance.](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/detecting_metamask.md#using-a-convenience-library)

[Call `web3.eth.sendTransaction`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the coinbase API https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/buy-widget and going from there